# Custom MessageConverter for Spring Cloud Stream is not being used when Spring Websocket added to service

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-websocket

I have a Scs microservice that consumes messages from a series of Kafka topics which all share the same abstract class.

I've registered a custom `MessageConverter` to deserialise the JSON messages that use this abstract class.

I wanted to push these messages I receive from Kafka through a websocket to our front end UI.  Once I added the config for the websocket broker the MessageConverter for Scs was no longer being used.  It looks like the MessageConverters registered for use with the websocket is taking precedence over the one that I've registered for use with Scs.

I've created a cut down example here https://github.com/jarebudev/scs-websocket-messageconverter-demo to demonstrate the issue - see the provided unit test.

Comment: Can you please raise an issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues

Comment: Sure, have raised https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1920

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer to this in case anybody else also runs into this issue...

The auto-configuration from Spring Websocket was interfering with the `MessageConverter`s from Spring Cloud Stream.

A fix has been made, see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/commit/eee1b1385c2864a32370a8e4758294d5efbe4cd5

In the meantime, I've worked around this issue by getting my Spring Cloud Stream config (containing the `@Bean` for my custom `MessageConverter`) to be applied before Spring Websocket.

In my case, both of my configuration classes were in the same package.

Before:

```
com.example.demo.config

  AppWebsocketConfig
  ScsConfig
```

After:

```
com.example.demo.config

  ScsConfig
  WebsocketConfig
```